# iPhone battery acting crazy since I came out of a cold room

Tags: iphone, battery

Last week, while the outside temperature was about 20 Celsius, I entered a cold room ( -6 Celcius) for about 20 minutes.

While in the room, my iPhone 6 suddenly shut down. I was not able to turn it on until about 20 minutes after getting out of the cold room (and charging it).

Ever since, my battery has been acting up. Dropping suddenly from 50% to 10%, or shutting down at 30%.

Comment: my iphone shut down itself(30%-40%) twice since last week,I only upgrade the system.

Comment: when my iphone 6 gets really hot from playing high resolution games I put it inside my refrigerator and sometimes in the freezer. But it didn't get any problem with the battery. Imagine the sudden change of temperature my iphone experienced.

Comment: @JaysonOng, that is a terrible idea. Putting a hot device in such a cold environment so quickly will cause condensation to form on the components and can ruin your device with water damage from the inside out. Just let it cool down naturally, it will tell you if it is too hot.

Comment: You damaged the battery. Apple says on their website that the operating temp is 32 to 95° Fahrenheit, and the non-operating temp is -4 to 113° Fahrenheit.

Comment: FYI, I did a full DFU reset today. So far so good I'll keep an eye on it for the next few days...

Comment: I spoke too fast. It just died on me at 21%. Then I plugged a charger (not even to the wall, just end iPhone side) and turned back on (21% still), only to shut down again a few seconds later.